# How were the passage divisions in the King James Bible determined?

Tags: kjv, versification

The Cambridge edition of the King James Bible that I have shows passage (or paragraph) divisions throughout.  I used to think that these were related to the [Eusebian Canons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eusebian_Canons), but this doesn't seem to be the case.  Matthew 14:6-12, for example, belongs to Canon VI.145, but my Cambridge edition (which I think is a reprint of a c.1900 edition) shows paragraph markings at 14:3 and then at 14:13.

Who determined these markings and how?

Answer (score 1):

https://rsc.byu.edu/archived/study-and-faith-selections-religious-educator/chapters-verses-punctuation-spelling-and

> ... **Today’s Chapters and Verses**
>
> Eventually, the Christians developed a need for a more precise way of
>   citing scriptural passages for the Old and New Testaments, especially
>   in the creation of concordances. The Christians incorporated in their
>   biblical texts the Jewish paragraph and verse divisions of the Old
>   Testament and the medieval chapter system of the New Testament.
>
> The creator of the **system of chapters** that is used to the present
>   time is Stephen Langton (1150–1228), a professor of theology in Paris
>   and later the archbishop of Canterbury. [20] Langton introduced his
>   chapter numbers into the Latin Bible—the Vulgate—in 1205, from which
>   they were transferred in the ensuing centuries to Hebrew manuscripts
>   and printed editions of the Old Testament as well as to Greek
>   manuscripts and printed editions of the New Testament.
>
> **The system of verse divisions that has prevailed to the present was the work of a Parisian book printer, Robert Estienne (Latinized as
>   Stephanus; 1503–59).** In the printing of his fourth edition of the
>   Greek New Testament in 1551, he added his complete system of numbered
>   verses for the first time. For the Old Testament, Stephanus adopted
>   the verse divisions already present in the Masoretic Text of the
>   Hebrew Bible, and within Langton’s chapters, he assigned numbers to
>   the verses. Following his own sense of logic as to the sense of the
>   text, Stephanus took it upon himself, also within the framework of
>   Langton’s chapters, to divide and number the verses in the New
>   Testament. His son reported that he did this work as he regularly
>   traveled between Paris and Lyon. Whereas he probably did much of the
>   work in his overnight stays at inns, his detractors spread the story
>   that he did it while riding on his horse, and they attributed what
>   they thought to be unfortunate verse divisions to slips of the pen
>   when the horse stumbled. In 1555, Stephanus published the Latin
>   Vulgate—the first whole Bible divided into numbered chapters and
>   verses. Soon, those divisions became standard in the printed editions
>   of the scriptures in Hebrew, Greek, Latin, and eventually in all of
>   the modern languages. **The first English Bible to have the numbered
>   chapters and verses of Langton and Stephanus was the Geneva Bible in
>   1560.**
>
> Some scholars have criticized Stephanus’s verse divisions as seemingly
>   arbitrary, citing the fact that although they often coincide with a
>   single sentence in English, sometimes they include several sentences,
>   sometimes they divide a single sentence, and sometimes they separate
>   direct quotations from the situation of the speaker. But clearly the
>   advantages of organizing the text for reading and finding passages far
>   outweigh any disadvantages.
>
> **In the King James Bible, the translators typographically created a new, separate paragraph in each verse by indenting the verse number
>   and first word and captitalizing the first letter of the first word,
>   even if it was in the middle of a sentence.** [21] ...

[Images of the original KJV 1611 showing the above:

https://www.1stdibs.com/furniture/wall-decorations/prints/beginning-genesis-1-1611-king-james-bible/id-f_10903621/?utm_content=test&gclid=CjwKCAjw06LZBRBNEiwA2vgMVVcmPSgNcmQLqRUYV633ZPx2gpyHdhWkBhfECJ2lCl11XUIIMg_OrBoCDN4QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds   ]

Thanks for the question. Interesting info found.

Comment: I think OP was asking about passages (groups of verses), not just verse and chapter divisions.